# Exit code 100 on apt-get update in BYON docker cloud build

Tags: docker, apt-get, docker-cloud

This is a [repost](https://forums.docker.com/t/non-zero-exit-code-100-on-byon-update-upgrade/36181) after there was no answer for 3 days.

I had a working version of bring-your-own (BYON) Docker cloud and have [successfully build](https://github.com/dmenne/gastro-docker) on it since months. When I tried to rebuild today, it returned a non-zero code on any `apt-get update`

```
....
Removing intermediate container db00ef7ced82
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I have put in a separate `apt-get update` for debugging to isolate the error.  I know that it should be combined with `&& apt-get upgrade` as shown in the log-file below.

When I omit `update`, all following `upgrade` work ok, so I assume it is some locking of updated lists, not a firewall issue. I also tried to remove the lists in the docker file before update with no change. I also have disabled caching in the Docker Hub dashboard for this project.

With Docker's internal build and on my own computer, the error does not appear.

Since this is running in a multi-container app on my server installed by docker, I do not know how to bash into to check details.

```
Building in User Node '0b9e8b1e-aa38-4099-b35c-96129f0f7238.node.dockerapp.io'...
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
Reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-89-generic
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2017-03-28T19:10:44.739403725+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.27
Version: 17.03.1-ee-2
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: ad495cb
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.7.5
Starting build of index.docker.io/dmenne/gastro-docker:latest...
Step 1/17 : FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest
---> 9daf220f0831
Step 2/17 : MAINTAINER Dieter Menne "dieter.menne@menne-biomed.de"
---> Running in 63c20055e4f6
---> d5f1d1bd8710
Removing intermediate container 63c20055e4f6
Step 3/17 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev sudo gdebi-core pandoc pandoc-citeproc libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcairo2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxt-dev
---> Running in 421fbe386f3b
Ign:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Get:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [88.5 kB]
Ign:4 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
Ign:5 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:5 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:6 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Err:6 http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
404 Not Found
Fetched 88.5 kB in 0s (236 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W:
The repository 'http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Removing intermediate container 421fbe386f3b
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev sudo gdebi-core pandoc pandoc-citeproc libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcairo2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxt-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Build failed: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev sudo gdebi-core pandoc pandoc-citeproc libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcairo2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxt-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Build failed with exit code 2
ERROR: Build in 'master' (55fd6a09) failed in 0:01:49
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on OSX. So I would think there is some wrong configuration on your OS or server? (DNS, firewall, ..)

Comment: I saw some cases where this helped: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https` but it's just working on my mac so that's a bit strange

Comment: Thanks for testing on OSX, that's the one I had no access to. I have tested it on Windows 10 and Ubuntu server, all works well, and it also worked before on the BYON cloud. The BYON installation is a bit of a black box because it is supplied by Docker and installed on my own server. Firewall not likely, because all `upgrade`s (once `update` is removed) work. I had already tried your suggestion (`apt-transport`) which is on SO, by putting it before the `update`. The problem is ONLY `update` which causes the error.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really know the BYON cloud. What DNS is it using? Maybe you can start your docker daemon with explicitly using DNS 8.8.8.8. (https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ using --dns).

Comment: `apt-get update` works Ok. Does `apt-get update` use a different web protocol? BYON brings its own Docker version (it is not the latest), so I have little influence on its working.